# is it wcag 2.0 AA accessible to leave both title and alt empty and add the text in a hidden paragraph text?

Tags: html, wcag2.0

Lets say the alt text of an image is too long and the image is linked as in below

```
 <a href="http://somelink.com" title=""> 
      <img src="someimage.png" alt=""/>
      <p class="hide_text">The complete alt text here as in too long to have any meaning to put in the title/alt above. Then is it accessible enough to put in the p tag?</p>
</a>
```

And I just hide the p text. Is that WCAG 2.0 AA accessible compliant then? If both title and alt is empty in such case and I include the image alt text in the p...**is that WCAG 2.0 AA accessible?**

Comment: Have you considered using the `longdesc` attribute on the `img`? It takes a URI, but that could probably be a `data://` URI if you don't want to spawn a seperate page.

Comment: longdesc is not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option in my case I have found is to use something like below

```
 <a href="http://somelink.com" title=""> 
      <img src="someimage.png" alt=" "/>
      <p class="hide_text">The complete alt text here as in too long to have any meaning to put in the title/alt above. Then is it accessible enough to put in the p tag?</p>
</a>
```

Put a space in the alt . So that when NVDA reads it, it is read as Link graphic link "The complete alt text here as in too long to have any meaning to put in the title/alt above. Then is it accessible enough to put in the p tag?"

Seems to be ok. I am just not 100% certain if I am violating any WCAG rules.

Answer (score 4):

If an image is the only element inside an anchor tag, its alt text would need to describe the link's destination rather than the image itself. If this description is too long, then it may be worth asking yourself whether this is appropriate.

This is a border-line WCAG pass/fail. The image could be said to fail 1.1.1 (non-text content) because it's not decorative but has no alt text. But the link itself would likely pass because the hidden text makes its destination programmatically determinable.

There's two reasons why I wouldn't use this approach:

1. Hidden text might not be available to access technology on all devices. I've seen this happen using VoiceOver on the iPhone.
2. Speech recognition users may have trouble clicking the link if seeing the image with no accompanying text doesn't give them enough info about how to instruct the recognition software to click the link.

So in conclusion I'd use alt text,  try to pare it down to a short description of the link's destination, and ensure that it's obvious from the image content how to click it using speech recognition.

Comment: Good points. However, the alt text or the title text is actually coming from an external source , aka in this case social media source. It just not feasible in this case for me. I do agree that the alt text need to limited.. but just not feasible. So....solution is?  Also, we use NVDA and JAWS for testing for accessibility. I am not concerned about voice-over of the iPhone as those are not standards in testing for accessibility. For me, I am more concerned with the standard popular screen readers only

Answer (score 0):

It is not WCAG AA compliant because if you put a `title` attribute on a `A` tag, it can't be empty.

> And I just hide the p text.

You can hide it as long as the screen-readers can read it (so no `display: none`)...

It might be WCAG AA compliant from many people's view, but you have to remember that not all people use a speech synthetizer and that such invisible information should be made available for everybody.

Also, link text should be as short as possible.